# Print like a dataframe vector pairs c++

Tags: c++

I have a map:

```
std::map<string , double> params{{a , 1}, {b, 6 }, {c, 7}{d,8} }
```

I want to print it like a python dataframe:

```
a b c d
1 6 7 8
```

Also, I dont want it to run twice.

```
void join_parameters(std::pair<string , double> param){
  
  std::map<string , double> params;
  
  params.insert(param);
  

  
  for(const auto& elem : params)
  {
      double a, b ,  c,d;
  
   if (elem.first =="a"){
          a = elem.second; }
        else if (elem.first =="b"){
            b = elem.second;}
       else if (elem.first =="c"){
          c = elem.second; }
        else {
         d = elem.second;        
        }

  }
             std::cout   << "d " << "a "<<  "b " << "c "<< "\n" << d << a << b << c <<std::endl ;

}
```

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only works for a map with 4 elements and it assumes that those elements have keys `"a"` till `"d"`. If that is the case then I would suggest you to use a different data structure, for example

```
struct params_t {
    double a,b,c,d;
};
```

If you do need the map then you should not make assumptions about number of elements or their keys.

You can use two strings to accumulate the two lines of output in a single loop:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string , int> params{{"a" , 1}, {"b", 6 }, {"c", 7},{"d",8} };
    
    std::pair<std::string,std::string> lines;
    for (const auto& e : params) {
        lines.first += e.first + " ";
        lines.second += std::to_string(e.second) + " ";
    }

    std::cout << lines.first << '\n';
    std::cout << lines.second << '\n';
}
```

Note that I changed the mapped type to `int` because it looks like you want to store integers. For `double` you need to adjust the code to get propper formatting.

Comment: i receive the pairs one at a time

Comment: I believe the "dataframe" thing refers to formatting the first and second row being element-aligned? Therefore, at the end of each iteration you could add spaces to the shorter string so that both have equal length. E.g. for a map entry { "a", 22}, note the two digits and the single char

Comment: @aryan then please try to clarify the question. You write "I have a map..." and this answer shows how you can print that map. The code you posted comes without comment or explanation and I didnt really understand what it is, I thought its your attempt to print the maps elements. Anyhow, if you receive the pairs one at a time, then the approach is the same. Accumulate the output in two strings and when you are done print the two lines

Comment: @aryan how do you know when to print the output? I mean the function is called for each pair one at a time, but you can only print all pairs when you know that you got them all.

Comment: I am aware that after a period of time, all values should be filled, and I check to see if any are null.

Comment: When you say accumulate, do you mean            s = std::accumulate(std::next(lines.first.begin()), lines.first.end(),
                                    std::to_string(lines.first[0]), space);

Comment: @aryan no I mean "accumulate" in the general sense of accumulating parts of the lines until you got the whole line to be printed once you got all elements. You can use `std::accumulate`, but I was just refering to adding the strings `lines.first += e.first + " ";`